# Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php

Вот код. В чем ошибка???

```
{
    $activate=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comm_users` WHERE `id_comm` = '$comm[id]' AND `activate` = '0' AND `id` = '".intval($_GET['yes'])."'");
    $activate=mysql_fetch_array($activate);//Пишет ощибку
    $activate_user=get_user($activate['id_user']);
    mysql_query("UPDATE `comm_users` SET `activate` = '1' WHERE `id_comm` = '$comm[id]' AND `activate` = '0' AND `id` = '".intval($_GET['yes'])."'");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mail` (`id_user`, `id_kont`, `msg`, `time`) VALUES ('0', '$activate_user[id]', '$user[nick] одобрил Вашу заявку на вступление в сообщество [url=/comm/?act=comm&id=$comm[id]]".htmlspecialchars($comm['name'])."[/url].', '$time')");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comm_journal` SET `id_comm` = '$comm[id]', `id_user` = '$activate_user[id]', `id_ank` = '$user[id]', `type` = 'in_comm', `time` = '$time'");
    msg("Вступительная заявка $activate_user[nick] одобрена");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Перестаньте пожалуйста использовать MySQL расширение. Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в версии 7.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL

Вы пропустили стоку с `mysql_result()`.

Данная ошибка произойдет, если у вас есть ошибка в SQL запросе.

Что бы проверить, что за ошибка воспользуйтесь кодом

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comm_users` WHERE `id_comm` = '$comm[id]' AND `activate` = '0' AND `id` = '".intval($_GET['yes'])."'");

if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```